# Cannot Search Arabic words in Generated pdf by RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, pdf, rdlc

[image]

This is the generated pdf by my RDLC report, As you can see when I copy the Arabic word and search it by CTRL_F it's actually misunderstood in some other language or formatting I don't know .

I actually set the report language to Ar-EG and I'm using Arial font
Can anyone tell me a solution or a workaround without converting the report to word

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDF with different programs like Chrome, Edge etc. then search?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, The same issue is on Chrome and Edge